# Getting a time date range

Tags: python, pandas

I am still learning my way around python, and this is somewhat a complicated question, 
having a table `pandas.DataFrame` like this:

```
           SAMPLE_TIME  TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut    State       Bypass  
0  2015-07-15 16:41:56      48.625   55.812   43.875        1            1   
1  2015-07-15 16:42:55      48.750   55.812   43.875        1            1   
2  2015-07-15 16:43:55      48.937   55.812   43.875        1            1   
3  2015-07-15 16:44:56      49.125   55.812   43.812        1            1   
4  2015-07-15 16:45:55      49.312   55.812   43.812        1            1
```

this is a big data set with entries every minutes over few weeks.
I am trying to get the range for every day, so basically ignoring the time and splitting by days

---

#### EDIT

I forgot to mention that this was imported from csv using `pd.read_csv()` which i think means that `SMAPLE_TIME` is not a `DatetimeIndex`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
#set to datetimeindex
df['SAMPLE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SAMPLE_TIME'])

print df
          SAMPLE_TIME  TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
0 2015-07-05 16:41:56      48.625   55.812   43.875      1       1
1 2015-07-05 16:42:55      48.750   55.812   43.875      1       1
2 2015-07-23 16:43:55      48.937   55.812   43.875      1       1
3 2015-07-23 16:44:56      49.125   55.812   43.812      1       1
4 2015-07-25 16:45:55      49.312   55.812   43.812      1       1

df = df.set_index('SAMPLE_TIME')
g1 =  df.groupby(lambda x: x.day)

for d,g in g1:
    print d
    print g
5
                     TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
SAMPLE_TIME                                                     
2015-07-05 16:41:56      48.625   55.812   43.875      1       1
2015-07-05 16:42:55      48.750   55.812   43.875      1       1
23
                     TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
SAMPLE_TIME                                                     
2015-07-23 16:43:55      48.937   55.812   43.875      1       1
2015-07-23 16:44:56      49.125   55.812   43.812      1       1
25
                     TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
SAMPLE_TIME                                                     
2015-07-25 16:45:55      49.312   55.812   43.812      1       1
```

Or you can group by day and aggregate by sum:

```
df = df.set_index('SAMPLE_TIME')
g1 =  df.groupby(lambda x: x.day).agg(sum)
print g1
    TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
5       97.375  111.624   87.750      2       2
23      98.062  111.624   87.687      2       2
25      49.312   55.812   43.812      1       1
```

Or group by year, month and day and aggregate by sum:

```
df['SAMPLE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SAMPLE_TIME'])

df = df.set_index('SAMPLE_TIME')
g1 =  df.groupby([lambda x: x.year, lambda x: x.month, lambda x: x.day]).agg(sum)
print g1
           TempBottom  TempTop  TempOut  State  Bypass
2015 7 5       97.375  111.624   87.750      2       2
       23      98.062  111.624   87.687      2       2
       25      49.312   55.812   43.812      1       1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can

```
df['SAMPLE_TIME'] = pd.to_datetime(df['SAMPLE_TIME'])
df.set_index('SAMPLE_TIME', inplace=True)
df_by_days = df.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('D')).agg()
```

to apply various aggregation functions as described in [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation). If you provide some detail on what you'd like to aggregate and how, happy to add an example.

Comment: I am getting this error `TimeGrouper is not defined`

Comment: I am getting a new error `TypeError: axis must be a DatetimeIndex, but got an instance of 'Index' ` I am guessing it is because it was imported as a string from CSV, I edited my question

Comment: Just convert the SAMPLE_TIME column to `DateTime`.